# Securing Google Actions and FireBase Endpoint

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google

I have made an action on Google Actions Console and a Firebase Function. The Firebase Function now is globally accessible to anyone. How can i restrict access to the firebase function with IP Whitelisting/Domain WhiteListing.

Also i saw that the Google Action does not send any API Key or APP Secret or Verify Token which can be verified by the Firebase Function. Hence anybody who can create the JSON of the Google Action Request can utilize my API.

I need to restrict access to this firebase function so that it is accessible only to the Google Action and no other access to the Firebase Fuction is allowed

Comment: Are you using Dialogflow or Actions SDK directly? The client library (if that's what you are using) has a builtin way to do request verification to check if its from Dialogflow or Google.